# Type-safe reverse-mapping of enums in Typescript 2.4

Tags: typescript, swagger-codegen, typescript2.4

The **Typescript 2.4** has introduced String Enums: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#string-enums

```
enum Colors {
  Red = "RED",
  Green = "GREEN",
  Blue = "BLUE",
}
```

Unfortunately there is also a notice:

> ... string-initialized enums can’t be reverse-mapped to get the original enum member name. In other words, you can’t write `Colors["RED"]` to get the string "Red".

The `swagger-codegen` generates the enums like this.

But how can we map properly from the string variable?